# Extending all activities from a common activity not working

Tags: android

I have an `application` which has four `activities`. All these activities should consist of a `toolbar` at the top and a `TabLayout` at the bottom. The `TabLayout` has 4 tabs. Clicking on a particular `tab` takes to one of the four activities.

Now I want to implement the code as follows

1) Create a Parent activity. The activity inflates a layout which contains the TabLayout.

2) All the other four activities should extend the Parent activity. These activities have their own xml layouts.

**ParentActivity.java**

```
    public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  }
}
```

activity_parent.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:text="One"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:text="Two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:text="Three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:text="Four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I am launching OneActivity I am not able to get the toolbar and the tablayout which I created in the ParentActivity. I only get  the content which I declared in the xml file of OneActivity.

My expected ui is this

[image]

This is what I get after launching.

[image]

Comment: It seems you want 4 Fragments in your Tabs. Not 4 Activities that subclass the Parent

Comment: no.. i want four activities. the example I have illustrated here is very simple. But in the real application I have four activities which in turn have fragments.

Comment: If you're calling `setContentView()` in the extended Activities, it's completely replacing the layout you set and initialize in `ParentActivity`.

Comment: It would be useful to see what the code and layout look like for OneActivity, but Mike is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling `setContentView()` in the extended Activities, it's completely replacing the layout you set and initialize in `ParentActivity`.

Instead, include a content `ViewGroup` - e.g., a `FrameLayout` with ID `content` - in `ParentActivity`'s layout, and inflate the extended Activities' layouts into it. This can be done rather simply by overriding the `setContentView(int)` method in `ParentActivity` as follows:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent);

    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content));
}
```

You can also move the setup and initialization common to all of the extended Activities into that override.