# Want to implement nav drawer and a base layout and my activity has a different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, navigation-drawer

I apologize in advance for being very vague about the question. I will provide as much detail as I can but since the code is for a company, I can only disclose so much.

I have a navigation drawer which is a base layout for all activities that I am using. I also want to use a third party library as a base layout INSIDE the navigation drawer. For example, I have `ClassNavigationDrawer` and `ClassThirdParty` who have a base layout and a frame layout for the activity that extends it.

ClassBaseThirdParty extends ClassNavigationDrawer and I want to extend ClassBaseThirdParty in my Activity.

The problem is that the ClassThirdParty layout is overriding the ClassNavigationDrawer layout. Is there anyway that I can have these two together?
Layout for my ClassNavigationDrawer

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

   <content>

   <drawer_content>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Layout for my ClassThirdParty

```
<thirdParty>

   <content>

   <third_party_layout_content>

</thirdParty/>
```

Comment: I recently answered a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892154).

Comment: I have two parent activities and then the individual activity will have its own layout.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: So, since I have 2 base layouts the second one is overriding the other and only one of the base layout works with the activity layout

Comment: Inflate the second layout into the content `ViewGroup` of the first, then inflate the third layout into the content `ViewGroup` of the second.

Comment: Yes. I am doing exactly that. I am overriding the setcontentview method in both places and am inflating the second one in the first itself. But since my parent elements for the two are different i guess the second one is removing the drawerLayout tag

Comment: We'll have to see your layouts and relevant code, then.

Comment: I can understand. Unfortunately, I cant share my code but thank you so much for trying.

Comment: We don't need to see any super-secret code; just the `inflate()` calls. Anyway, it sounds like you're not specifying the correct `ViewGroup` to inflate the second layout into