# Android Navigation Drawer with multiple Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, event-handling, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a BaseActivity with navigation drawer and extend it in other activities so that I  can reuse the the navigation drawer code.

What I have figured out so far:

- I can use fragments to do this (which I can do).
- I can use a BaseActivity and inflate the content area (Frame layout with id as “main_container” in my case) to show other activities. In this case I have figured out how to click on navigation drawer items to change activity.

However, when I have a button inside one of my activity (example activityA) and I want to load another activity (activityB), show a toast, etc. by clicking that button, the click listener does not work unless I write the code for the listener inside the onCreate method of the BaseActivity.

To me this does not make sense because it forces me to write all the codes inside the BaseActivity which is not the most efficient way of writing code (the activities acts like fragments so I can just use fragments instead).

What I want to know is, how to load the navigation drawer on all activities extending the BaseActivity, and still allow the activities to retain their behaviours.

Code samples

**My activity_home.xml (BaseActivity)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/custom_tool"
        layout="@layout/custom_bar"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nav_display"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml (activityA)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="147dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="105dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="105dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/search_bar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/input_default"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/search_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="228dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_default"
    android:text="@string/search"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_bar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the app is initially loading the “main_content” of the BaseActivity is inflated with the activity_main layout.

When I clicked the search_button inside the activity_main.xml, I want to load another activity which is only happening when I am writing the code inside the base activity.

**HomeActivity**

```
package com.example.naisse;


import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected static int position;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
protected FrameLayout frames;

Button searchButton;
/**
 *  This flag is used just to check that launcher activity is called first time
 *  so that we can open appropriate Activity on launch and make list item position selected accordingly.
 * */
private static boolean isLaunch = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.custom_tool);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    frames = findViewById(R.id.main_container);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    /*inflating the layout with activity_main*/
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, frames);



    searchButton = findViewById(R.id.search_button);

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /*removing the activity_main and inflating they layout with activity_result*/
            frames.removeAllViews();
            getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_result, frames);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

**Extending MainActivity with HomeActivity**

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.naisse;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends HomeActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please show us how you're extending `HomeActivity` to make `MainActivity`.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I'm following your description correctly, but when you call `setContentView()` in `MainActivity`, it completely replaces the layout that was set and initialized in `HomeActivity`. Instead, you want to inflate `MainActivity`'s layout into the one that was set in `HomeActivity`. You can do this rather simply by overriding `setContentView()` in `HomeActivity`, like is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36893003). You would replace `R.layout.activity_parent` in that example with `R.layout.activity_home`, and `R.id.content` with `R.id.main_container`.

Comment: The case you have mentioned is not exactly similar to mine. I have the 'toolbar' and 'navigation drawer' in my home activity along with a frame layout to load content "main_content" dynamically. I can load another activity (main_activity) onCreate of the HomeActivity the first time inside the "main_content". So, i can see the navigation drawer, the toolbar and the content of the main_activity when my app starts.

Comment: My problem is when i click a button (the search_button in my case), i want the "main_content" to dynamically change to another activity_layout which I can do, if the event handler is inside the HomeActivity instead of MainActivity.
This means, if I have another event handler in activityC then I have to write the code in HomeActivity instead of activityC which does not make sense.
How to reuse the codes for navigation drawer and toolbar like I did and not write all the code in HomeActivity, that is my question.

Comment: Oh, OK, I see where the confusion is, then. You're conflating layouts with Activities. Just because you inflate a layout named `activity_main` in `HomeActivity` does not mean that that is a separate `Activity`. You're not actually using the `MainActivity` class. You're just adding `View`s to `HomeActivity`, which is why you have to set that `OnClickListener` there, and setting it in `MainActivity` has no effect. Layouts are just "blueprints" for `View` hierarchies. They are not inherently tied to `Activity` classes.

Comment: I see. That makes sense now. I'm just showing the layout hence the click listeners are not working when written in their respective classes. How do I trigger not only the layout but also the activity class?

Comment: Instead of those `inflate()` calls, you would use `startActivity()` to launch the corresponding `Activity` class. If your startup "page", though, is to be `MainActivity`, you'd need to change the `LAUNCHER` `<activity>` in the manifest to be `MainActivity` instead of `HomeActivity`, and remove that `...inflate(R.layout.activity_main, ...)` call from `HomeActivity`'s `onCreate()`. Adding that `setContentView()` override I mentioned above would then take care of inflating the extending Activities' layouts correctly. Your `OnClickListener` should then work in `MainActivity`.

Comment: I would mention, though, that this kinda goes against the navigation drawer pattern, which is generally used to navigate within a single `Activity`. These days, `Fragment`s are usually used with a nav drawer, but there's no hard and fast rule that says you can't do this with multiple Activities. I'm just pointing it out, FYI.

Comment: So, the most efficient way to write code, if i have multiple activity and not fragment, is copy and paste the navigation drawer code for all activities?

Comment: Nah, you don't have to copy/paste anything. Your setup right now is really close to what is needed. Setting and initializing the base layout in `HomeActivity` will automatically cause that to happen for each `Activity` that extends it. Your `HomeActivity` should look something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aBCOxDVAaTcNuvFnCwDKoeSwrW9u8lKF/view?usp=drivesdk. Notice everything is in that `setContentView()` override, now. You don't really need an `onCreate()` in that class. `MainActivity` looks just like above, but now you can put that `OnClickListener` there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. So the idea is to put everything that i want to share across activity inside the **overrided** **setContentView** method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For answer and understanding, please read the discussion between me and Mike M.

What I was initially doing was inflating the "main_container" with layout and therefore the Activity class was not getting triggered. To do that, I had to override **setContentView()** method inside the BaseActivity (HomeActivity in my case) and put every sharable code such as toolbar and navigation drawer inside that.

My new HomeActivity.class

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawer;
protected FrameLayout frames;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    // Set the base layout
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // Find the content container
    frames = findViewById(R.id.main_container);

    // Inflate the extending Activity's layout into it
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frames);

    // The rest of the base setup
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.custom_tool);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}

}
```

And now the toolbar and navigation drawer is shared across all activities.

Comment: A couple of points about answers: (a) there is no need to add [solved] to the title - there is a fully-featured answer acceptance system, which should be used instead. Also, (b) comment streams are often deleted, and thus should not be referenced from answers proper - if you want to record an answer, please write up the gist of the conversation in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised so few are interested in doing this in all these years.  Maintaining the duplicated code of the DrawerLayout stuff in xml files of all activities is pretty silly.

I tried the self-answer from @Mill3r, unfortunately overriding setContentView conflicts with databinding and causes crash.

Instead of setContentView I create a method in the base activity like:

```
public void setContent(View contentView) {
    // Find the content container
    frames = findViewById(R.id.main_container);

    frames.removeAllViews();
    frames.addView(contentView);

    // The rest of the base setup
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.custom_tool);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}
```

Then in all activities derided from the base, call this function after setting databinding, like:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
setContent(binding.getRoot());
```